Why is My Specific Path Override Not Working in Apple App Site Association File
I'm trying to configure my Apple App Site Association (AASA) file to handle deep links for my app. I want to ensure that the path /bbs/thread/* is included, and it should override the more general path /bbs/*. However, it seems that my current configuration is not working as expected. Here is the relevant part of my apple-app-site-association file:

{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
            {
                "appIDs": [
                    "XXXXXXX.io.deweb.messageboard.stg"
                ],
                "components": [
                    {
                        "/": "/_/*",
                        "exclude": true
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/bbs/thread/*"
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/bbs/*",
                        "exclude": true
                    },
                    {
                        "/": "/*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

From my understanding, the specific path /bbs/thread/* should override the more general exclusion of /bbs/*, but it doesn't seem to be working. Can someone help me understand why this configuration isn't behaving as expected and how I can fix it?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

"I want to ensure that the path /bbs/thread/* is included, and it should override the more general path /bbs/*." I don't think you can do that. Exclude means exclude. The thread rule doesn't partially override the exclude rule.

@matt I see, thanks for your comment, so looks like the only way is to list each path separately
